# How to iterate over key and values within a pd.DataFrame?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a pd.DataFrame containing 3 dictionaries that looks like this:

```
               0                                                  1
0     land_cover  {'y2001': [120], 'y2002': [120], 'y2003': [120...
1           ndvi  {'y2001': [3513], 'y2002': [3411], 'y2003': [3...
2  precipitation  {'y2001': [568], 'y2002': [568], 'y2003': [450...
```

I want to iterate over each series to get rid of the 'y' before the years (keys) and of the [ ] around corresponding values.

Comment: before which year? Can you provide the desired output?

Comment: want to eliminate 'y' before all years in each series. Ideally, the output would be a json that looks like this: 
 {
    "name": "timeseries",
    "table": [
        {
            "name": "ndvi",
            "time": [
                2001.0,
                2002.0,
                ....
             ], 
             "y": [
                3513,
                3411,
                 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.loc[:,1] = [{ k[1:]:v[0] for  k, v in row.items()} for row in df[1]]
```

Assumptions

`k[1:]` assumes that y appears only as the first character of the key in the dictionary, otherwise `replace` would be a better (but likely to be slower) approach.

`v[0]` assumes that each list has only one value, otherwise you might need to convert these to strings and join them.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a targeted regular expression replacement.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0,'y123', 'y00123']})

print(df)

        A
0       0
1    y123
2  y00123


df1 = df.replace({r'(y)(\d+)' : r'\2'},regex=True)
print(df1)


       A
0      0
1    123
2  00123
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the dictionary in each row like you normally would:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [{'y2001': None, 'y2002': None}, {'y2001': None}]})
>>> df['x_new'] = [{k.replace('y', ''): v for k, v in row.items()} for row in df['x']]
>>> df
                                x                         x_new
0  {'y2001': None, 'y2002': None}  {'2001': None, '2002': None}
1                 {'y2001': None}                {'2001': None}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you built the data frame yourself and have access to the original data, I recommend reformatting it such that the dictionary keys, (`y2002`), are indices, the data labels (`land_cover`) are column headers.  Then the values in the dictionary be the entries in the data frame instead of dictionaries.

This would allow you to access the data more readily and allow easier access to the data labels that you wish to change.

```
d1 = {'y2001': [120], "y2002": [120]}
d2 = {'y2001': [3513], "y2002": [3411]}
d3 = {'land_cover': d1, "ndvi": d2}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d3, columns=['land_cover', 'ndvi'])

      land_cover    ndvi
y2001      [120]  [3513]
y2002      [120]  [3411]
```

You can also Transform the dataframe to swap columns and index if you prefer years as columns.

```
df = df.T
             y2001   y2002
land_cover   [120]   [120]
ndvi        [3513]  [3411]
```

You can remove the "y" by accessing the list of column headers and using string modifications.

```
oldcols = list(df.columns.values)
newcols = [w.replace('y', '') for w in oldcols]
print(oldcols)
col_dict = dict(zip(oldcols, newcols))
df = df.rename(columns=col_dict)

              2001    2002
land_cover   [120]   [120]
ndvi        [3513]  [3411]
```

Finally, you can convert all the lists to integers using `df.applymap()`

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: int(x[0]))

            y2001  y2002
land_cover    120    120
ndvi         3513   3411
```

Answer (score -1):

Supposing that 'd' is your dataframe, set the value of 'd.index' as the following:

```
d.index=pd.Index([2001,2002,...])
```

You can also iterate

```
d['land_cover'].values
```

and set it with

```
d['land_cover'].values[0]=120
```